# How to delete inserted directory names for `find-file` input?

Tags: minibuffer, find-file, deletion

I've been trying to figure out how to erase directories faster when I use `find-file`
in vanilla Emacs.
An example is [Doom Emacs](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs), you press backspace once, and erase the entire directory, but when I try to do the same thing on vanilla Emacs, I need to erase the entire directory name. How I can modify this behavior to make my Emacs file navigation faster?

Comment: The question isn't clear. You seem to contrast a wished-for *"erase the entire directory"* with an existing need to *"erase the entire directory"*. Please make clear the distinction you're trying to draw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `C-x DEL` (`C-x <backspace>`) do what you want? That's bound by default to `backward-kill-sentence`, which generally deletes all or most of what's already in the minibuffer before point.

You can of course bind that command to another key. And you can do that in a minibuffer keymap, if you don't want to do it globally. Globally `DEL` (`<backspace>`) is bound by default to `backward-delete-char-untabify`.

Comment: instead of erasing everything, I want to return one directory

Comment: ok, found it, just used `backward-kill-word`, thanks :D